# Jsch with spongycastle rather than bouncycastle on Android

Tags: android, ssh, bouncycastle, jsch, spongycastle

I currently have an Android application connecting to my router via ssh using a password. I'm looking to improve this so I can use keys but I am having real issues. From what I understand the version of bouncycastle included with android is a crippled version and because of this ssh keys don't work with jsch. I have looked at spongycastle which claims to be a fuller implementation. Below is the result which  is basically the same as using bouncycastle, Auth Fail.

```
10-26 18:18:23.528: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Connecting to 192.168.88.1 port 22
10-26 18:18:23.538: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Connection established
10-26 18:18:23.548: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Remote version string: SSH-2.0-ROSSSH
10-26 18:18:23.548: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.44
10-26 18:18:23.548: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
10-26 18:18:23.618: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
10-26 18:18:23.618: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
10-26 18:18:23.628: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
10-26 18:18:23.628: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
10-26 18:18:23.688: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
10-26 18:18:23.688: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
10-26 18:18:24.058: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): ssh_dss_verify: signature true
10-26 18:18:24.058: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,2): Permanently added '192.168.88.1' (DSA) to the list of known hosts.
10-26 18:18:24.058: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
10-26 18:18:24.058: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
10-26 18:18:24.078: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
10-26 18:18:24.088: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
10-26 18:18:24.108: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
10-26 18:18:24.108: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Next authentication method: publickey
10-26 18:18:24.108: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Authentications that can continue: password
10-26 18:18:24.118: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Next authentication method: password
10-26 18:18:24.128: INFO/System.out(10642): Log(jsch,1): Disconnecting from 192.168.88.1 port 22
10-26 18:18:24.138: WARN/System.err(10642): com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
```

There's not a great deal of logging information from jsch to help me work out what's wrong.

I think I'm using pretty standard code for this:

```
static {
        Security.addProvider(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
```

In OnCreate I'm removing the original bouncycastle provider

```
        Security.removeProvider("BC");
```

Then I add the identity just before trying to connect

```
        jsch.addIdentity(key_filename);

    Properties sshProp = new Properties();
    sshProp.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(sshProp);
    session.connect();
```

Has anyone done this successfully? Am I forgetting something?

Edit point additional info:

As I said in the comment I'm now suspecting that the key isn't even being tried when I switch the key and test on sshd version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7

```
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 122/256
debug2: bits set: 519/1024
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug2: bits set: 537/1024
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: monitor_read: 5 used once, disabling now
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: KEX done
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method none
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0
debug2: parse_server_config: config reprocess config len 638
debug2: input_userauth_request: setting up authctxt for root
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method none
debug2: monitor_read: 7 used once, disabling now
debug1: PAM: initializing for "root"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "nexus"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug2: monitor_read: 50 used once, disabling now
debug2: monitor_read: 3 used once, disabling now
Failed none for root from 192.168.88.31 port 37807 ssh2
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method password
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method password
debug1: PAM: password authentication failed for root: Authentication failure
Failed password for root from 192.168.88.31 port 37807 ssh2
Received disconnect from 192.168.88.31: 3: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
```

I can see no attempt to use the key, whereas from a pc

```
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method publickey
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0
debug2: input_userauth_request: try method publickey
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys2, line 2
```

I can see the key method being used. Below is the code I'm using for testing, not pretty but functional. I know it's horrible but password does contain the filename and path of the key to be used when authtype == AUTHENTICATION_METHOD_KEY

```
public static String testSSHCommand ( String username, String password, String hostname, int port, String command, int authtype) throws Exception {    

    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    JSch.setLogger(new Logger() {
            public boolean isEnabled(int i) {
                return true;
            }

            public void log(int i, String s) {
                System.out.println("Log(jsch," + i + "): " + s);
            }
    });


    if (authtype != AUTHENTICATION_METHOD_PASSWORD) {
        Log.v("AUTHMETHOD","authmethod was "+authtype+" with key filename of "+password);
        jsch.addIdentity(password);
    } 

    Session session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);

    if (authtype != AUTHENTICATION_METHOD_KEY) {
        session.setPassword(password);
    }


    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfig(prop);

    session.connect();

    if (session.isConnected() ) {
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)          
        session.openChannel("exec");      
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        channelssh.setOutputStream(os);
        channelssh.setCommand(command);
        channelssh.connect();        
        channelssh.disconnect();

        return os.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect you are using a wrong public key. Does the login with the same key files (public + private) work from a normal PC Java program?

Comment: I don't do PC based java development, however the keys are fine I can use them on my pc to ssh into a server box to test.  I'm actually beginning to suspect that the keys aren't even being tried. (see edit)

Comment: Comparing this with a normal PC Java would help to isolate the problem, i.e. if it is related to your crypto provider or to your own code.

Comment: I've tried without spongycastle too - same results. Perhaps I'm missing some obvious step, since the key exchange isn't attempted (it seems) Is there a way to be more  debug info from jsch? This is on android 2.3.3

Comment: I don't know much about Android, but showing your complete JSch accessing code could help to find the problem (if it is there).

Comment: Added sample code (not using spongycastle).

Answer (score 1):

I tested your method by wrapping it into a [class with main method](https://github.com/ePaul/jsch-documentation/blob/fuzzytest/examples/FuzzyTest.java), and with this, it works in a normal Java 6 JRE (no BouncyCastle), with JSch-0.1.45 (a modified version with more logging output) and "OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3" sshd.

I added a `session.disconnect()` and some sleeps to the code, though.

I have no Android here to see if this would make any difference.

Here is my local output:

```
authmethod was 2 with key filename of /home/paulo/.ssh/id_rsa
Log(jsch,1): Connecting to localhost port 22
Log(jsch,1): Connection established
Log(jsch,1): Remote version string: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
Log(jsch,1): Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.45
Log(jsch,1): CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
Log(jsch,1): aes256-ctr is not available.
Log(jsch,1): aes192-ctr is not available.
Log(jsch,1): aes256-cbc is not available.
Log(jsch,1): aes192-cbc is not available.
Log(jsch,1): arcfour256 is not available.
Log(jsch,1): CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
Log(jsch,1): diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
Log(jsch,1): kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
Log(jsch,1): kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
Log(jsch,1): expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
Log(jsch,1): ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
Log(jsch,2): Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Log(jsch,1): Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
Log(jsch,1): Next authentication method: publickey
Log(jsch,1): Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Log(jsch,0): packet received, type: 91
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_CONFIRMATION received, channel: 0
Log(jsch,0): packet received, type: 94
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA received, channel: 0, len: 13
Log(jsch,0): packet received, type: 96
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF received, channel: 0
Log(jsch,0): packet received, type: 98
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST received, channel: 0, type: [B@1ad086a, want reply: false
Log(jsch,0): packet received, type: 97
Log(jsch,1): SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE received, channel: 0
Log(jsch,1): Disconnecting from localhost port 22
Log(jsch,1): Caught an exception, leaving main loop due to Socket closed
Output: »Hallo, Welt!
«
```

(I called the program with arguments `paulo -key /home/paulo/.ssh/id_rsa localhost 22 hello`, so it executes the default Hello World program on the target machine, and in German, because this is my configured locale.)

Comment: So are we saying that jsch doesn't work with keys on android?

Comment: I'm saying that I don't know the reason. You could try my test program with your key on your computer for comparison, though. (And maybe test the more-debugging-output version of JSch in the linked GitHub repository, to see if you get more information.)

Comment: I'm being extremely dim today, I can't find your updated jar from the link you gave, could you provide the direct link?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a jar, though you can compile the source code yourself (use `ant compile` in the root directory). I'll have a look if I can generate a jar, though probably not today.